# Access modifiers for properties of a struct

Tags: solidity, truffle, struct

I am relatively new to Solidity. I am following a tutorial and came up with the following contract:

```
contract Election {
  struct Candidate {
    uint id;
    string name;
    uint voteCount;
  }

  mapping (uint => Candidate) public candidates;
  // keep a counter to track the number of candidates
  uint public candidatesCount;

  constructor () public {
    addCandidate("Candidate 1");
    addCandidate("Candidate 2");
  }

  function addCandidate (string memory _name) private {
    candidatesCount++;
    candidates[candidatesCount] = Candidate(candidatesCount, _name, 0);
  }

}
```

I am using Truffle for development. Now, once the contract is deployed locally, I am running these on the truffle console:

```
> Election.deployed().then(instance => app = instance)
> app.candidates(1).then(res => candidate1 = res)
```

So basically I am getting an instance of a `Candidate` from `candidates` to `candidate1`. Now, when I am assigning the `voteCount` property of `candidate1` from the console like this:

```
> candidate1.voteCount = 100
```

To my surprise the voteCount is actually set to 100. I assumed the properties of a struct to be private. I tried adding the `private` access modifier to the struct properties but it is throwing errors.

What is the valid/correct way to add access modifiers to the struct so that the `voteCount` property cannot be set without a setter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not changing anything in the contract state. You're setting `candidate1` to be an instance of the contract in the JavaScript sense. This is in the client. You can set arbitrary properties and retrieve set values. That activity won't affect the contract state storage in any way.

Indeed, even after you set that, you should see the contract was unaffected with.

`candidate1.candidatesCount().then(function(response) { console.log(response.toString(10); });`

I expect it should print `2`.

Instead of modifying the contract abstraction Truffle gave you, you should be *using it* to inspect the contract.

If you wanted to change the contract state then you would send a transaction to your `addCandidate()` function.  If you're using truffle:

`candidate1.addCandidate(arguments).then(...` This will return a transaction hash and you have to wait until it mines, then you'll see the test returns count of 3. I think you should call your contract abstration `elections` (not `candidate1`) to reflect that it is a JavaScript representation of the deployed `Elections` contract.

Hope it helps.